# what is the real time usage of WS-TRUST and WS-FED

Tags: authentication, ws-federation, thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture-ident-model, ws-trust

i read about 2 WS* protocols , WS-TRUST  and WS-FED. but i am confused about real time scenario  how to use these protocols . can anyone let me know in which scenarios i can use WS-TRUST and WS-FED ? it would be very helpful if someone can tell which is best among these 2 protocols for securing a REST service and a normal.ASPX page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WS-Federation is for web applications (e.g. ASP.NET WebForms or MVC)
WS-Trust is for SOAP-based web services (e.g. WCF)

for HTTP services you have to look into OAuth2.